Triangular correlations?
As used in my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/652022/11887, triangular correlation seems to be a useful concept/terminology that could see more use. But searching I cannot see much use, some examples below. Maybe some other terminology is in use?   Some examples from literature:


This is student course grades versus (y-axis) absence from classes, it seems like % absence from classes gives an approximate upper bound for grade. From On Triangular Correlation by Othmar W Winkler. He says

Despite an evident relationship between absence from class and semester grade, the
coefficient of correlation, using linear regression, was r = -.18024. Interpreting this $R^2 = .03249$ seemed to indicate that knowing the % of absence from classes barely helps to explain -- 3% of
the scatter of grades received in those courses.

which without the plot seems to be very misleading. Another example from that paper:

Which he includes to show examples from sciences, not only social sciences. Taken from
"Shake holes, A morphometric Field Project for Sixth-Form
Geographers," Geography, Vol. 65 pt. 3, July 1980, No. 288." (which I cannot find by internet search).  Other interesting examples can be found in Interactive-engagement versus traditional methods: A six-thousand-student
survey of mechanics test data for introductory physics courses by Richard R. Hake.
Another paper (shorter) by the same author, containing the same figure (and not walled) is A simple graphic method to assess correlation.
How should such data be analyzed and presented? Correlation coefficients do not seem to be useful ... Other examples? Are some other terminology in use?

I tried to digitize the points from the first plot. The result below, in R format
dput(plot_data2)
structure(list(percent_missed = c(1.24, 1.1, 3.36, 1.75, 12.72, 
5.12, 8.26, 3.65, 13.3, 17.54, 7.82, 0.51, 0.8, 3.14, 5.99, 3.14, 
0.73, 3.14, 5.7, 9.21, 13.3, 16.96, 22.22, 18.79, 24.34, 28.07, 
12.06, 6.51, 7.68, 8.7, 9.43, 9.14, 11.99, 14.4, 17.69, 22.15, 
19.15, 23.25, 33.48, 0.8, 0.88, 3, 2.85, 5.41, 5.26, 7.24, 7.24, 
9.21, 10.09, 13.38, 3.14, 3.07, 0.73, 2.56, 4.68, 7.02, 7.38, 
8.92, 10.38, 13.3, 16.45, 10.53, 12.43, 8.48, 6.73, 6.65, 8.26, 
9.58, 12.21, 14.25, 15.13, 18.2, 24.34, 22.37, 39.25, 2.92, 5.7, 
6.8, 9.43, 13.01, 13.3, 17.03, 19.3, 18.42, 34.58, 36.48, 23.98, 
2.85, 7.38, 11.92, 7.02, 14.18, 16.81, 21.93, 24.71, 32.6, 37.43, 
18.42, 7.31, 8.92, 16.23, 16.3, 19.74, 21.78, 21.78, 24.49, 27.7, 
44.88, 41.59, 14.4, 11.99, 22.22, 24.63, 33.04, 53.36, 7.82, 
21.49, 23.68), grade = c(20, 19.6, 19.26, 18.93, 18.96, 18.61, 
18.58, 18.25, 18.22, 18.31, 17.95, 17.8, 17.67, 17.8, 17.63, 
17.4, 17.29, 17.12, 17.31, 17.43, 17.58, 17.75, 17.63, 17.33, 
17.09, 17.29, 17.17, 17.09, 16.96, 16.97, 16.91, 16.83, 16.6, 
16.62, 16.78, 16.78, 16.29, 16.28, 16.35, 16.72, 16.41, 16.81, 
16.42, 16.77, 16.4, 16.62, 16.28, 16.47, 16.44, 16.16, 16.14, 
15.85, 15.56, 15.16, 15.46, 15.61, 15.96, 16.01, 16.01, 15.92, 
16.01, 15.53, 15.45, 15.27, 15.16, 14.99, 15, 14.78, 14.69, 14.72, 
15.06, 15.39, 15.7, 15.12, 15.24, 14.32, 14.6, 14.3, 14.14, 14.32, 
14.02, 14.59, 14.54, 14.01, 14.36, 13.99, 13.68, 13.47, 13.7, 
13.47, 13.22, 13.09, 13.19, 13.28, 13.28, 13.32, 13.15, 12.88, 
12.58, 12.06, 11.94, 12.49, 12.45, 12.66, 12.33, 12.48, 12.3, 
12.66, 12.27, 11.63, 11.13, 11.22, 11.81, 11.05, 9.55, 9.57, 
9.78, 9.27)), row.names = c(NA, -118L), class = "data.frame")


Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/653545/regression-techniques-for-a-triangular-scatterplot

I can't tell what you mean by 'triangular correlations', despite having looked at this question and the links (the "On triangular correlations" link doesn't let me download the pdf without creating an account), and looking up the term online.

Also Methods For Measuring Non-Linear Correlation?

@dherrera: I found another link, not walled, with some of the same info. But basically, triangular correlation means that the points in the scatterplot are (approximately) concentrated within a triangle. A typical case could be that income is more or less upperbounded by education (?), with a few outliers ...

I don't really see why you consider the correlation coefficient to be "not useful" here. A magnitude around 0.2 can indicate a detectable but weak relationship, which is qualitatively what we have in the first plot. The "percentage of variance explained" is usually rather small, even with high correlation coefficients - a correlation of 0.7, for example, often denotes a rather strong relationship, despite the fact that one variable doesn't even explain 50% of the variability in the other. Agree it doesn't tell the whole story by itself, but it's still useful.

@kjetilbhalvorsen Would the GAMLSS approach I suggested at your linked thread meet your intended purpose? Or are you looking for a more straightforward numerical summary, like a correlation coefficient?

@mkt: The GAMLSS approach is interesting, I will have a look at it. I am really looking for ideas ...

Re figure 9.3: the quoted statistics are clearly incorrect; $R^2$ is substantially greater than $0.03.$  Unless there is severe and selective overplotting of points, this $R^2$ is around $0.3$ to $0.4$--an order of magnitude greater than Winkler reported.  Their subsequent "model" has little to recommend it because it is arbitrary, ungrounded in any theory, and more complex than most alternatives.  This forum doesn't provide adequate space for discussing the myriad other approaches in common use: you're basically asking for a treatise on statistical modeling of bivariate relationships.

@whuber: I cannot see I am asking for a treatise on statistical modeling of bivariate relationships. This triangular relationship is quite special, I think I see it in the wild, and have not seen any discussion of it. It looks useful to have such a discussion, and the answes now seems quite useful ...

I still have no clear concept of what you might mean by a "triangular relationship."

Re the second paper: the analysis is so clearly wrong (84% for $R^2$??  Slope of $-0.16$??  Rescaling by arbitrary conversion to percentages??), and so completely unsupported by theory (I'm being nice here--the analysis contradicts basic regression theory) that I wonder whether the author is some kind of a crank.  This journal "MedCrave" is known as a predatory fake journal.  By no means can it be considered any kind of "literature," -1. You do us all a disservice by quoting it and linking to it.

@whuber: the only reason I linked to it was that I was asked for a nonwalled source of the figure

Even so, you rely on papers solely by the same author who is posting that junk in such a journal.  I am left not knowing what you might possibly mean by "triangular regression" and suspecting it is something useless or worse.

It's not clear to me how this is different from other non-linear relationships. Based on some of the examples you gave, it seems that perhaps what is of interest is that the association is not as strong as expected given what we know about the data generating process. Is this perhaps a methodological/data collection issue, and not a statistical one?
We can simulate a 'triangular' distribution quite easily if both variables are skewed.
In R --
library(dplyr)

# modified from 
# https://github.com/debruine/faux/blob/master/R/distribution_convertors.R
norm2gamma <- function(x, skew, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, 
                       mu = mean(x), sd = stats::sd(x)) {
  
  skew_in = skew
  if(skew_in<0){
    x = x*-1
    skew = skew * -1
  }
  
  shape = (2/skew)^2
  p <- stats::pnorm(x, mu, sd)
  if (rate == 1 && scale != 1) rate <- 1/scale
  x_out = stats::qgamma(p, shape, rate = rate) %>% 
    scale(center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
  attributes(x_out) = NULL
  if(skew_in<0){
    x_out = x_out*-1
  }
  return(x_out)
}

correl = -.3 
samplesize = 1000
dat = MASS::mvrnorm(n = samplesize, mu = c(0,0), 
           Sigma = matrix(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, 
           c(1,correl, correl, 1))) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(dat) = c("x1_norm", "x2_norm")

dat$x1_gamma = norm2gamma(x = dat$x1_norm, skew = 2)
dat$x2_gamma = norm2gamma(x = dat$x2_norm, skew = 2)

plot(dat$x1_gamma,dat$x2_gamma)


And we can evaluate this relationship using various methods, which are sensitive to different kinds of linear/non-linear associations:
# Pearson correlation
cor(dat$x1_gamma, dat$x2_gamma, method = "pear")
[1] -0.225034

# Spearman correlation
cor(dat$x1_gamma, dat$x2_gamma, method = "spear")
[1] -0.2990289

# Distance correlation
energy::dcor(dat$x1_gamma, dat$x2_gamma)
[1] 0.2529908

# Quantile regression
quantreg::rq(x1_gamma ~ x2_gamma, data = dat, tau = 0.5)
Call:
quantreg::rq(formula = x1_gamma ~ x2_gamma, tau = 0.5, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    x2_gamma 
 -0.2958456  -0.1633275 

Degrees of freedom: 1000 total; 998 residual

# Cross rank increments
XICOR::xicor(dat$x1_gamma,dat$x2_gamma)
[1] 0.07443907


Ecologists have used quantile regression for extreme upper quantiles to estimate what the unconstrained relationship between an input $X$ and output $Y$ might be, when other unmeasured factors actually constrain the value of $Y$ at many measurement sites.
One such reference is Quantile regression for ecologists by Brian Cade and Barry Noon (PDF). Their Figure 2 looks a lot like your first image.

SEPARATE THE MARGINAL DISTRIBUTIONS FROM THE DEPENDENCE
This is exactly what we get from copula theory and Sklar's theorem.
Setting aside technical details, we know from a basic probability class that the margins of a multivariate distribution are independent when the product of the margins equals the joint distribution.
Sklar's theorem shows that, at least under nice conditions, the joint distribution equals that product of the margins along with something else. That something else relates to the copula.
Part of how we can separate the margins from the copula is through the probability integral transform. Therefore, to check out how the apparent dependence in a plot is affected by the margins vs the true dependence structure, you can perform an empirical probability integral transform.
If we apply this to the data in the answer by David B, we get this.
library(dplyr)

# modified from 
# https://github.com/debruine/faux/blob/master/R/distribution_convertors.R
norm2gamma <- function(x, skew, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, 
                       mu = mean(x), sd = stats::sd(x)) {
    
    skew_in = skew
    if(skew_in<0){
        x = x*-1
        skew = skew * -1
    }
    
    shape = (2/skew)^2
    p <- stats::pnorm(x, mu, sd)
    if (rate == 1 && scale != 1) rate <- 1/scale
    x_out = stats::qgamma(p, shape, rate = rate) %>% 
        scale(center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
    attributes(x_out) = NULL
    if(skew_in<0){
        x_out = x_out*-1
    }
    return(x_out)
}

correl = -.3 
samplesize = 1000
dat = MASS::mvrnorm(n = samplesize, mu = c(0,0), 
                    Sigma = matrix(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, 
                                   c(1,correl, correl, 1))) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(dat) = c("x1_norm", "x2_norm")

dat$x1_gamma = norm2gamma(x = dat$x1_norm, skew = 2)
dat$x2_gamma = norm2gamma(x = dat$x2_norm, skew = 2)

par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(dat$x1_gamma, dat$x2_gamma, main = "Original Data")
plot(
    ecdf(dat$x1_gamma)(dat$x1_gamma),
    ecdf(dat$x2_gamma)(dat$x2_gamma),
    main = "Transformed Data"
)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))


I don't see much dependence between the two variables (maybe a slight negative trend). Rather, that triangular shape seems come from the margins.
This can be a useful plotting trick. For instance, look at the following. It looks like an interesting relationship, right, that same kind of triangular correlation?

The variables are independent, which we can see from the lack of a pattern in the plot of the data after the empirical probability integral transform.

set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
x <- rexp(N, 4.1)
y <- rexp(N, 4.1)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(x, y, main = "Original Data")
plot(ecdf(x)(x), ecdf(y)(y), main = "Transformed Data")
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

In terms of making predictions, what independence between variables means is that, for every value of one variable, the conditional distribution of the other is the same as the unconditional. In the above simulation, no matter what the value of $X$ is, the distribution $Y\vert X = x$ is the same as $Y$ itself.
You can see how this contrasts with dependence.
set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000000
x <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
p <- 0.3 + 0.4*x
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)

In the above simulation, $Y\sim\text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$. However, $Y\vert X = 0 \sim\text{Bernoulli}(0.3)$, and $Y\vert X = 0 \sim\text{Bernoulli}(0.7)$.
